# MySQL order by two colums (and before and after now)

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

If I have two colums:

```
number | vip_date 
22     | 22.03.2013
32     | 12.01.2013
38     | NULL
44     | 06.01.2013
20     | 30.03.2013
10     | NULL
```

I want to sort by number and by date so i do something like ...`ORDER BY number DESC, vip_date DESC`.

Results are sorted by date and the 2 rows with NULL date are sorted by number. 
Question is, how to order by number rows with dates after NOW() and order by number dates before NOW()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare if the row is null, and sort after that:

```
ORDER BY number DESC, (vip_date IS NULL) ASC, vip_date DESC
```

`(vip_date IS NULL)` will be `1` if the row is `NULL`, and `0` if it's not. Hence, 0 is before 1 (and that's why we're sorting ascending).